# shortcut to show a single channel (solo mode) in the graph editor ?

Tags: shortcut, graph-editor

Does anyone knows if there is a shortcut to show only a single channel in the graph editor ? (eg. key + click)
I always have to uncheck all channels but one to work... And that's quite annoying.

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select the channel and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to "Hide Unselected Curves". This option is also found in the *Channel> Hide Unselected Curves* menu in the graph editor.

You can then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to "Reveal Curves" to bring the hidden ones back.