# How can I quickly manage visibility of channels across multiple objects in the graph editor

Tags: animation, graph-editor

Say i have made an animation i want to modify. I know that i just need to tweak the rotation of every bone in the spine by rotating X on every bone across every frame. I want to maintain all existing rotation while adding some on, so i use the graph editor and move the curve up. But finding and adjusting the x rotation curve is hard because every other curve (rot yzw, scale xyz, loc xyz etc..) is overlapping it and confusing me.

The only way i know of to deal with this atm is to go through every object in the graph editor list and do the same thing: Un-checking visibility on every instance of a channel that isn't the x rotation channel. This is very time consuming.

Something better might be if i could only see the transformation channel matching the 3D manipulator i have selected in the 3d view. Or if there were a way to hide all other transformation curves that aren't x rotation at the same time.

I'd like to know if there is a faster approach to managing the visibility of channels in the graph editor.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42225/shortcut-to-show-a-single-channel-solo-mode-in-the-graph-editor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit curves only for selected objects, or filter unneded curves by various types.

**Hide channels for other objects**
Enable *[Only Include channels relating to selected objects and data](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html#header-controls)* in the Graph Editor header. With this enabled you can edit channels of only selected objects which decreases amount of data to handle with.

[image: including channels only for selection]

#### Filtering channels

**Filtering by type**
Enable *Filters* in the window header. From there select which type of animation data is desired to be shown, from 8 categories of animation data: scene, world, nodes, objects transforms, meshes, datablocks related to modifiers, lamps and cameras. Click <kbd>LMB</kbd> to select / deselect multiple:

[image: filtering animation data by type]

*Only transfroms animation data is shown above because it is what location / rotation keyframes of objects are.*

**Filter by keyword**
Enable filtering by keyword; the filter will be applied while you type it in.

[image: filter by keyword]

*"X" is typed as keyword; shown all keyframes which have letter X in their property.*

#### Visibility of channels

Also it's possible to hide all but selected channel, see [shortcut to show a single channel (solo mode) in the graph editor ?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42225/shortcut-to-show-a-single-channel-solo-mode-in-the-graph-editor), or disable visibility for multiple channels.
You could do that quickly by clicking Eye icon of one channel and hover it over Eye icons of other channels up / down without releasing the mouse. The channels will be hidden.

[image: hiding multiple curves]

Comment: You can also use keying sets. see: https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/actions.html?highlight=key%20set#keying-sets and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7636/what-is-a-keying-set-and-how-does-it-fit-into-the-animation-workflow

Comment: @cegaton thanks, I didn't try that one, seems promising. I think deserves another answer.

Comment: In particular 'Filter by word' was something i hadn't explored, and best answered my question for handling many of one kind of channel. Although i'm not familiar in manipulating keying sets.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the built-in features mentioned by [@Mr Zak](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1245/mr-zak), you can install the [Highlight Channels](https://github.com/j3soon/blender-highlight-channels) addon to achieve this with hotkeys:

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the Highlight Channels addon.